# TypeError: QWidget(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType

Tags: python, pyqt5

Me encuentro programando una pequeña interfaz gráfica en QtDesigner (PyQt5) y encuentro problemas en dos secciones del código:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\VB a Python\Ejercicio 2\descuentos.pyw", line 29, in <module>
    mi_app = Ventana()
  File "C:\Projects\VB a Python\Ejercicio 2\descuentos.pyw", line 13, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, parent)
TypeError: QWidget(parent: QWidget = None, flags: Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType] = Qt.WindowFlags()): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
>>>
```

El código en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
import sys

import descuentos

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets





class Ventana(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = descuentos.Ui_Frm2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.BtnAceptar.clicked.connect(self.aceptar)


    def aceptar(self):
        sueldo = self.ui.TxtSueldo.toPlainText()
        extra = self.ui.TxtExtra.toPlainText()
        neto = int(sueldo) + int(extra)
        self.ui.TxtNeto.setText(str(neto))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    mi_aplicacion = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mi_app = Ventana()
    mi_app.show()
    sys.exit(mi_aplicacion.exec_())
```

He intentado  hacer los siguiente:

```
class Ventana(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
            QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self.parent)
            self.ui=Ui_FrmAlumnos()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            self.ui.BtnAceptar.Clicked.connect(self.Aceptar)

    def Aceptar(self):
        n1: self.ui.TxtNota1.toPlainText()
        n2: self.ui.TxtNota2.toPlainText()
        n3: self.ui.TxtNota3.toPlainText()
        n4: self.ui.TxtNota4.toPlainText()
        n1: int(n1)
        n2: int(n2)
        n3: int(n3)
        n4: int(n4)
        promedio= (n1+n2+n3+n4)/4


        self.ui.TxtPromedio.setText(str(promedio))
```

pero ahora el error es:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\Ejercicios\Ejercicio 3\alumno.pyw", line 29, in <module>
    mi_app= Ventana()
  File "C:\Projects\Ejercicios\Ejercicio 3\alumno.pyw", line 7, in __init__
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self.parent)
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'sip.simplewrapper' object but received a 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Agradecería que me pudieran explicar qué ocurre de malo y cómo resolverlo. Soy bastante nueva en esto y necesito de consejos para reducir este tipo de inconvenientes.

Comment: La pregunta va bien, excepto la parte de pedir recomendaciones de fuentes de estudio, eso queda fuera del alcance de [ask]

Answer (score 1):

El error está en la línea:

```
super().__init__(self, parent)
```

**`super()`  pasa automáticamente la referencia a la instancia (`self`) al método de la clase padre** (en este caso `__init__`). Esto hace que se esté llamando al inicializador de `QWidgets` de la siguiente forma realmente:

```
QWidget.__init__(self, self, parent)
```

el segundo argumento (descartando `self`, que se pasa siempre automáticamente) es `flags` y es al que le pasas `parent`, mientras que a `parent` le pasas `self`...

Como le pasas el valor de `parent` (`None` en este caso) a `flags` y éste no acepta `None` como valor (solo acepta `Qt.WindowFlags` o `Qt.WindowType`) como la propia anotación de tipos muestra en el error tienes el error mostrado.

La solución es tan simple como cambiar la línea de llamada al inicializador del padre por:

```
super().__init__(parent)
```

o

```
super().__init__(parent=parent)
```

En el segundo caso, intentas llamar al inicializador del padre de forma  explícita, pero tienes dos problemas:

- En este caso la referencia a la instancia (`self`) no es pasada de forma automática, debes pasarla tú explícitamente.
- `self.parent` no es el atributo `parent`, `self.parent` una vez inicializado el widget es el método `QWidget.parent()` que es un método heredado por `QWidget` de `QObject` que retorna el padre del widget en este caso.

Deberías hacer:

```
QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
```

pero mejor usa `super()`.

Además tienes dos errores más no relacionado con el error incial:

- No es:

  ```
   self.ui.BtnAceptar.Clicked.connect(self.Aceptar)
  ```

  es:

  ```
  self.ui.BtnAceptar.clicked.connect(self.Aceptar)
  ```

  el método se llama `clicked` no `Clicked`.
- No es

  ```
  n1: self.ui.TxtNota1.toPlainText()
  ```

  debe ser:

  ```
  n1 = self.ui.TxtNota1.toPlainText()
  ```

  `=` no `:`.

El código debería quedar así:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import alumno


class Ventana(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

        self.ui = alumno.Ui_FrmAlumnos()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.BtnAceptar.clicked.connect(self.aceptar)

    def aceptar(self):
        n1 = self.ui.TxtNota1.toPlainText()
        n2 = self.ui.TxtNota2.toPlainText()
        n3 = self.ui.TxtNota3.toPlainText()
        n4 = self.ui.TxtNota4.toPlainText()
        n1 = float(n1)
        n2 = float(n2)
        n3 = float(n3)
        n4 = float(n4)
        promedio= (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4
        self.ui.TxtPromedio.setText(str(promedio))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mi_aplicacion = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mi_app = Ventana()
    mi_app.show()
    sys.exit(mi_aplicacion.exec_())
```

Quedaría solventar el problema de si el usuario no ingresa alguna de las notas, pero eso es otra cuestión y no es un error realmente.